# ajaxCRUD.com multiple relationships

Tags: ajax, foreign-keys, relational-database, crud, foreign-key-relationship

I'm really not sure I'll find someone to help with that but let's give it a try!

I'm using the CRUD script from ajaxCRUD.com and I want to create more than one relationship between my tables.But, when I try to do so, only the first relationship appear.

I want to link my `fruits` table with the `properties` table:

```
$tblDemo = new ajaxCRUD("Fruits", "my_fruits", "id", "../");
$tblDemo->defineRelationship("id", "properties", "id", "color");
$tblDemo->defineRelationship("id", "properties", "id", "taste");
```

If I want to get the color AND the taste from the same "relationshipped" table, only one of them will show.

Any hint on how I make a relationship between two (or more) columns of the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example

```
$tblFriend->defineRelationship("idCliente", "clientes", "idClientes","nombreCliente");
$tblFriend->defineRelationship("idCategoria", "categorias", "idCategoria","nombreCategoria");
```

I see the two relationship perfect. No extra code or anything

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a view in your database to concatenate color and taste, something like:

```
CREATE VIEW v_properties AS
SELECT id, CONCAT(color, ' - ', taste) AS color_taste
FROM properties;
```

and then reference that view in your code:

```
$tblDemo->defineRelationship("id", "v_properties", "id", "color_taste");
```

Would that work?

Or, if it works with views, create a view that is just an alias for properties:

```
CREATE VIEW properties2 AS
SELECT * FROM properties
```

and use properties2 in your second link:

```
$tblDemo->defineRelationship("id", "properties", "id", "color");
$tblDemo->defineRelationship("id", "properties2", "id", "taste");
```